Ubuntu does not start, a black screen appears, and recovery mode doesn't work
Ubuntu doesn't start, a black screen appears, and recovery mode doesn't work.
(initramfs) exit
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems: Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; is /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--1v does not exist. Dropping to a shell! 
[ 1.136618] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): 
Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PC00.LPCB.E CO. XHPP], ΑΕ_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[ 1.137758] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.T200. TMP due to previous error 1.137839] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PC00.LPCB.E
[ 1.137853] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.T200. TMP due to previous error
BusyBox v1.36.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.36.1-3ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.


What are you asking ?

In English please ...

I am trying to solve this problem, as it is not solved in known ways
